# Sum up cells based on conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I appreciate this could be treated as a simple question.  I have been trying to figure out where I'm going wrong as I'm sure it is something simple ... from the Strategy Exposures tab you can see that his strategies are either *macro or tactical* I have a table (below) and have been asked to to sum up the required exposure for Macro and for Tactical depending on what is there. I want to create two separate cells.  One which adds up 'Macro', and the other which adds up 'tactical'.

```
Strategy    ExposureDescription ExposureRequired (USD)
EUR_MACRO       DAX INDEX        2,000,000
EUR_MACRO       FTSE INDEX       4,000,000
EUR_MACRO       CAC40 INDEX      1,100,000
EUR_MACRO       S&P INDEX       10,000,000
JPY_MACRO       NKY INDEX        4,000,000
JPY_MACRO       S&P INDEX       34,000,000
USD_TACTICAL    S&P INDEX        4,000,000
JPY_TACTICAL    NKY INDEX        6,000,000
JPY_MACRO       S&P INDEX        3,000,000
```

Currently, I have tried variations of: `=SUMIF(B$3:B$11,"*MACRO*",D$3:D$11)`
however this formula keeps giving an output of `0`.  Table ranges from (diagonally) B2 - D11.

Comment: Build helper column that pulls macro and tactical. `=MID(B1,FIND("_",B1)+1,8)`?

Comment: `SUMIF()` with a wildcard works for me.

Comment: @pnuts I'm trying not to use VBA and rather use a simple function like what I have shown...  I tried using what findwindow provided to first pull which are 'macro' and which are 'tactical' and then add them but this seems like an overkill?

Comment: You're sure it doesn't work? Double check your ranges and such. Also note that if you drag this formula anywhere, it's going to change and could output the wrong info.  I'd make the references absolute (`$B$3:$B$11`, etc.).  Please see my own screenshot of your formula working (it resolves to `58100000`): http://i.imgur.com/ISh0Q2T.jpg

Comment: @BruceWayne Hi Bruce, I tried exactly that: =SUMIF($B$3:$B$11,"*macro*",$D$3:$D$11)  and triple checked the range.  I'm getting an outcome of zero still.  Any ideas if there's a weird sheet setting?

Comment: @vtj808 - just making sure, but in Excel, you used `"*macro*"` (note the `*`) and typo in the comment left that out?  Perhaps it's some odd formatting thing.  Try this: Create a NEW workbook.  *Manually* enter your data (not copy paste, just enter some sample rows), and try the formula on those rows. See if that works. (It could be a weird sheet setting, which is why I recommend trying it on a completely new one, and no copy/pasting to prevent any formatting to be copied too).

Comment: @BruceWayne apologies, I typed the above but in Excel, correct I used =SUMIF($B$3:$B$11,"*macro*",$D$3:$D$11).  I tried a new workbook and nada.. I also just tried to call it from another work sheet, using: SUMIF(StrategyExposures!B3+StrategyExposures!B3:B11,"*macro*",StrategyExposures!D3+StrategyExposures!D3:D11).  I am now getting a pop up saying I have an error.  I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @pnuts I just tried summing column d, this seems to work fine ...

Comment: @BruceWayne I did use the * (astrich) both times, including in the example I pasted above but I have just realised it is not showing up on stackoverflow ... I wonder if my Excel is reading the formula correctly? I'm using a mac.

Comment: Excel for Mac also uses the `*` wildcard.  Have you tried creating a totally new workbook, typing your data in there and see if it works? If it works in a new workbook, then we can assume some kind of setting or formatting is throwing it off in your current workbook.

Comment: @BruceWayne I just created a new workbook again after closing down the other one completely and this time it does work!   I think you're right, it must be some sort of formatting?

Comment: Good to know!  I think it's perhaps with the text aspect.  You said you could `Sum()` the numbers, correct?  Can you also do misc. math with them? (Do some random math with your numbers) - this will make sure they're being read by Excel as Numbers.  Perhaps the formula is having an issue reading your text.

Comment: @BruceWayne I got it! It's extremely odd however I had to disable the macros.  I re-opened the sheet with the macros disabled and it fixed the issue! Wow - I didn't know this ...

Comment: There must've been some macro preventing it.  Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Thanks a lot @BruceWayne for the help. You triggered the find :)

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out after all of this, the SumIF function was working okay when we created a new workbook with brand new data.  This prompted me to close down the current sheet which I was having formula issues with, disable the macros and re-try.  It worked a charm.  I have never experienced this before however as @brucewayne suggested, their must've been some conflict based on one of the macros.  Unsure what yet, will look into this and see if I can figure it out. If I do will post more. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Do you know much about VB? It's likely a macro in a worksheet or module.  With the workbook (the funky one) open, hit ALT+F11 to open the VBEditor, that's where you'd be able to browse the project for any macros. I'll bet that it's because calculation is turned off?  Also check File--> Options, then go to "Formulas" and make sure "Workbook Calculation" is set to Automatic.  Perhaps that got put to Manual?

Comment: @BruceWayne sorry for the delay, thank you for taking the time to share this! I have tried it as you said and it worked.  Really appreciated your help with this one :)  Thanks again!